# how to run scheduling on spring application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have try use this code

```
@Component("SchedulingTaskCustomerTransfer")
public class SchedulingTaskCustomerTransfer{

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?"))
    public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        System.out.println("schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
    }
}
```

i also have try to run on 12:35 jakarta time. but when i set like this

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 35 * *", zone= "Asia/Jakarta")
```

i got error like this

```
 'scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression': Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 35 '35' in cron expression "0 0 12 35 * *"
```

but when i see my code i got error annotations are not allowed here. my question is how to allowed this annotation on my spring application ? and how to set my scheduling task run everyday at 10pm ?

Comment: Are you tried to put '@Transactional' above  '@Scheduled' ?

Comment: You have two closing brackets in your ```@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?"))``` .   **))**   => **)**

Comment: `..for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 35`

Comment: you programmed hours (12) and days(35), try `"0 35 12 ? * * *"` , see also: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html,  http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/cron-expressions-in-teamcity.html

Comment: every day at 10PM: `"0 0 22 ? * * *"`;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your task every day at 10 pm, this configuration should work.

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 22 * * *")
```

Have you enabled Spring Scheduling mechanism?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Main {
   ...
}
```

By the way, there is a syntax error in your code (extra closing bracket). Maybe that's the issue?

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?"))
```

Comment: @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 15 * ?", zone= "Asia/Jakarta") i have try use this code and hope it is run on 12.15pm jakarta time. but when i see my code my cron not run on 12.15pm jakarta time. what is error in here. oh i see i forgot for add @enableScheduling on my code